# ISIM / ITIM REST connection via Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm trying to create REST connection to ISIM (6.0). According to: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/289830/how-to-authenticate-to-isim-via-rest-apis/ there are 3 steps to do that.
I've managed to create below script

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$URL = "https://<hostname>:9443/itim/"
$LOGIN_URL = "$($URL)restlogin/login.jsp" 
$REST = "$($URL)rest/"
$LTPA = "$($URL)j_security_check"

$cookiejar = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer 
$webrequest = [System.Net.HTTPWebRequest]::Create($LOGIN_URL); 
$webrequest.CookieContainer = $cookiejar 
$response = $webrequest.GetResponse() 
$cookies = $cookiejar.GetCookies($LOGIN_URL)

$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.Cookies.Add($cookies)
$body = ""

$Headers = "j_username=<username>&j_password=<password>"

$LTPA = "https://<hostname>:9443/itim/j_security_check?j_username=<username>&j_password=<password>"
$VAR = Invoke-RestMethod  -URI $LTPA -body $cookies -Method POST #-ContentType "application/json" #-body $cookies



Write-Host "3"
$ME = "https://<hostname>:9443/itim/rest/systemusers/me"
$VAR2 = Invoke-RestMethod  -URI $ME -body $cookies -Method POST
```

however I'm unable to get any connection only:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Does anyone could help me with that?

Comment: 404 is generally a client side error. Are you sure your URL/protocol is correct?

Comment: It turns out that there was was a type-o in URL. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is really old ...
The "Get LTPA Token" call (itim/j_security_check) indeed return a 404 :(.
The token is returned in a cookie though.
You'll have to somehow "convince" the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet to ignore the 404.